# trying to display a 3rd levl jquery menu on IE8 but it is hidden behind everything else, ff no probs

Tags: jquery, css, internet-explorer

I have a jquery menu which displays great for the first level drop down, I'm trying to mod it to have a third level. It works fine on FF and chrome but the thrd level element is getting lost behind the rest of the page on IE. I have gone over this carefuly for hours and can't see what the issue is so would really appreciate some help.

btw I have set up Z-index for every single parent and child element so that is not an issue.

heres the link

http://www.synergycc.com  there is a sample third level menu under services

thanks

Comment: The link provided isn't working.

Comment: our hosting is kind of slow so it seems like our website occasionally is unavailable but the link is right. sorry for any inconvience

Comment: anyone else? the link does definitely work

Comment: I'm looking at it, it does seem to be definitely wrong...Not sure what to do to fix it. What I have done in the past is to remove the item from being a submenu and append it to the body - you should know the position you want from the event. Then, setting the z-index pushes it to the top.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried setting the width of the sub div to auto rather than a fixed with?

```
ul#topnav li .sub{width:auto;}
```

You might also want to try to apply a float fix to the any parent class that has floated elements:

```
.floatFix {
    zoom: 1;
}

.floatFix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
}
```